# ¿Cómo reemplazar varios caracteres con php7?

Tags: php7

Estoy realizando un módulo que permite descargar un archivo Excel con PhpSpreadSheet con información de una base de datos. La columna específica que necesito, lo guardé de forma manual con los caracteres especiales de HTML5 (para que en todas las pantallas se tomen bien). El problema está en que al descargar el documento, se muestran los caracteres especiales de forma literal (`&Aacute;`, por ejemplo). He intentado cambiar los caracteres con `str_replace()`, pero me lo repite muchas veces y sólo una (1) de estas veces se modifican bien los caracteres. Esto lo hago de esta forma:

$consultar_recinto=$mysqli->query("SELECT nombre_centro FROM usuarios, centros WHERE usuarios.documento_usuario='$doc' AND usuarios.id_centro=centros.id_centro GROUP BY centros.id_centro");

```
        while ($r=mysqli_fetch_array($consultar_recinto)) {

            $r['nombre_centro']=str_replace("&Aacute;", "Á", $r['nombre_centro']);
            $r['nombre_centro'].=str_replace("&Eacute;", "É", $r['nombre_centro']);
            $r['nombre_centro'].=str_replace("&Iacute;", "Í", $r['nombre_centro']);
            $r['nombre_centro'].=str_replace("&Oacute;", "Ó", $r['nombre_centro']);
            $r['nombre_centro'].=str_replace("&Uacute;", "Ú", $r['nombre_centro']);
            $r['nombre_centro'].=str_replace("&Ntilde;", "Ñ", $r['nombre_centro']);

            echo $r['nombre_centro'] . "<br><br>";

            //$sheet->setCellValue('I' . $contador_r . '', $r['nombre_centro']);

        }
```

Aquí hay una imagen de lo que me devuelve `$r['nombre_centro'];`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el documento Excel, el cambio sólo es visto en una sola repetición, los demás aún se muestran con caracteres especiales.

Agradecería mucho a quien me pueda ayudar.

Answer (score 1):

Tal y cómo muestra la [documentación de `str_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php), puedes utilizar de primer y segundo parámetro un `array` de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
$r['nombre_centro'] = str_replace([
    "&Aacute;",
    "&Eacute;",
    "&Iacute;",
    "&Oacute;",
    "&Uacute;",
    "&Ntilde;",
], [
    "Á",
    "É",
    "Í",
    "Ó",
    "Ú",
    "Ñ",
], $r['nombre_centro']);
```

Algo que te recomiendo, es que escribas una función que haga esto mismo, así evitas reescribir código cada vez que necesites remplazar letras con acentos.
Puedes optar por algo como:

```
<?php
function remplazar_acentos($cadena) {
    return str_replace([
        "&Aacute;",
        "&Eacute;",
        "&Iacute;",
        "&Oacute;",
        "&Uacute;",
        "&Ntilde;",
    ], [
        "Á",
        "É",
        "Í",
        "Ó",
        "Ú",
        "Ñ",
    ], $cadena);
}

echo remplazar_acentos($r['nombre_centro']);
```